# B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Please help, I am creating custom policy. and below is requirement
Custom policy user SignUp SignIn flow :-
Sign up Flow :-

1. user enter his Email or Contact number for otp verification;
2. After verification user will enter his details without password
   . Details :- First Name, Last Name, Nationality, email or Phone number.  Pass Number;
   . All screens will be splited (email or Phone number verification page, validate otp page, details page )
   . if user enters his email for otp verification then get the Phone number in details page or if user enters his Phone number then get the email in details page
   Sign In Flow :-
3. user enters his contact number or email;
4. user will get the otp and verify that otp;
5. if otp is correct jump to the app homepage;
   . I don't want password, signup or signin process will be without password,
   I tried this [text](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup) policy for splitting but I don't know how to modify this to archive email or phone number only  based steps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-via-email-or-phone).

Each screen in the flow needs to be a self-asserted policy, and any fields to enter need to be an output claim.

To pre-populate a claim, make it an input claim in that policy.